# TableView isn't updating data even though it recognizes input?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

So I have 5 rows and on selection they pass an integer with the row number to my second view controller.

Each number has its own array with items and should then return the amount of items for the row specified.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MasterCell";

    MasterCell *cell = (MasterCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];


if (radInt == 0) {
     cell.textLabel.text = @"LM";
     NSLog(@"My return should have been LM");

}
if (radInt == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Restauranger";
    NSLog(@"My return should have been Rest");
}
    if (radInt == 2) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [shoppingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    if (radInt == 3) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [annatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    //cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-icon1.png"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


    return cell;
}
```

This is my code just to test it out and it doesn't work. NSLOG works correctly but the data simply wount update...  What have I done wrong? It Nslogs LM every time but it also has 1 in the log which is the selected row (radInt).

New approach

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MasterCell";
    MasterCell *cell = (MasterCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil)
        cell = [[MasterCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (radInt == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"LM";
        NSLog(@"My return should have been LM");

    }
    else if (radInt == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Restauranger";
        NSLog(@"My return should have been Rest");
    }
    else if (radInt == 2) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [shoppingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if (radInt == 3) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [annatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Noes";
    }


    //cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-icon1.png"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
```

The view before ----

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SecondViewController *enjoy = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Livsmedel"]) {
        [enjoy setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        enjoy.radInt = 0;
        NSLog(@"0");
    }

    if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Restauranger"]) {
        [enjoy setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        enjoy.radInt = 1;
        NSLog(@"1");
    }

    if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Shopping"]) {
        [enjoy setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        enjoy.radInt = 2;

    }
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Annat"]) {
        enjoy.radInt = 3;
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"main" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: It seems there is no connection between the `indexPath` and your selection variable (`radInt`).

Comment: Have you logged radInt to see what it is? How are you passing that into this table view?

Comment: In the previous view I have the approach above, adding now

Comment: I am logging the variable radInt in the 2nd view and it sure works so the problem is in the table data I suppose.

Comment: The problem is, that you're creating an new instance of SecondViewController with your alloc init, instead of getting the one youhave in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath: if you connect the segue in the storyboard from the cell to the next controller. What you need to implement is prepareForSegue:. Your code should look something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender:(id) sender
{
    NSInteger row = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
    SecondViewController *enjoy = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"Livsmedel"]) {
        [enjoy setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:row]];
        enjoy.radInt = 0;
        NSLog(@"0");
    }

    if ([[array objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"Restauranger"]) {
        [enjoy setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:row]];
        enjoy.radInt = 1;
        NSLog(@"1");
    }

    if ([[array objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"Shopping"]) {
        [enjoy setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:row]];
        enjoy.radInt = 2;

    }
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"Annat"]) {
        enjoy.radInt = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :D it really worked. I had no idea that you could do prepareForSegue to send the data in storyboards. Thanks alot!